# TS error when filtering on results in Promise.allSettled from axios request

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I am using `axios` and `Promise.allSettled` to make a number of API calls. I am also using TS in this project.

```
const settledResults = await Promise.allSettled([
    axios.get("./one.json"),
    axios.get("./two.json"),
]);

const fulfilledResults = settledResults.filter(result => result.status === 'fulfilled');
```

This line gives the following error, which I can fix by adding `any`:

settledResults.filter((result: any) => result.status === 'fulfilled');

> Parameter 'result' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Has anyone got an idea what the type here should be?

Have tried `AxiosResponse` with `Promises` and anything else I could think of with no luck.

Comment: Hmmm in my case the `settledResults` has implicitly the correct type of `PromiseSettledResult<AxiosResponse<any, any>>[]`. Maybe something else is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the type {[key:string]:string} or {status: string} so the filter can compare?